# How to unlink a symbolic link CentOS?

Tags: linux, centos

I am still fairly new to CentOS 6.5 and linux in general. In my haste to remedy a solution, I created a link from a suggestion online without thinking much about it. However I need to remove the link, and I am not sure what is the best way to do this.

The command used was as follows:

```
ln -s /dev/sda2 /dev/root
```

If i run

```
ll /dev/root
```

I get the following link reported:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Jun 13 06:08 /dev/root -> /dev/sda2
```

How to safely remove the link? I read a suggestion saying using the unlink command, but I'm not sure, what is the correct command to run to unlink the specific command I used.

Comment: The only thing that could happen if you "rm /dev/root" is that if you used /dev/root in fstab or other places, it will fail to mount the partition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
rm /dev/root
```

Don't over think it